# iOS: How to call webservice when app is terminated by the user

Tags: ios, iphone, location

I am trying to update the location to server when the app is not running. I am getting the location update when user location is changed but the web service is not getting called... Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you are getting your terminology incorrect? Terminated means not running, therefore it is totally impossible to do anything if the app is not running. However due to the fact you say: " I am getting the location update", perhaps you actually mean when the app is in the background? An app in the background and a terminated app are two totally different things. The code in Vanson's answer is applicable if the app is in the background, but obviously it is not applicable if the app is terminated.

Answer (score 0):

You need implementation an background task like this

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"MyTask" expirationHandler:^{
        // Clean up any unfinished task business by marking where you
        // stopped or ending the task outright.
        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    // Start the long-running task and return immediately.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        // Do the work associated with the task, preferably in chunks.

        [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    });
}
```